# How to include subdirectories in shared object build

Tags: c++, c, build, cmake

I have reorganised my project and I'd like to know how to include the source code from subdirectories in the build of my shared object. I now have the following directory structure:

```
src/
    Component/
        CMakeLists.txt
        SubComponent1/
            src1.h
            src1.cpp
        SubComponent2/
            src2.h
            src2.cpp
```

My CMakeLists.txt currently looks like:

```
add_library(MainProject SHARED src1.cpp src2.cpp)
```

How do I now update it so that it will build the folders below? Do I also need to add CMakeLists.txt to the SubComponentX folders?

Thank you

Comment: The tag additions for C, and C++ have *what*, exactly, to do with this question?

Comment: If you need to compile files in subdirectory into the main library, just add this files into you `add_library()` call. If you want to build other libraries, use *additional* `add_library()` calls, either in main *CMakeLists.txt* or in subdirectories. So, what is a problem?

Comment: @WhozCraig, because it is used to build C and C++ applications. It's also something C and C++ developers have experience with so that I can get useful answers to my question, coincidentally your comment doesn't fall into the 'useful' category.

Comment: @jdie8274j Not gonna argue about your intention. Both of those tags are intended for questions *about those languages, including code of said-same* (and usually the tag description states this; ex: hover over the C++ tag). That was the only reason I asked. If you think casting a broader net to unrelated tags in hopes of trawling up something "useful" will work, then grand. Glad you found an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want the sources to be buit into a single library, just change the paths in your project:

```
add_library(MainProject SHARED
    SubComponent1/src1.cpp
    SubComponent2/src2.cpp
)
```

If you want each of your subdirectories to build separately, you can use `add_subdirectory` in `src/Component/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(SubComponent1)
add_subdirectory(SubComponent2)
```

In this case, you will indeed need a CMakeLists file in `src/Component/SubComponent{1,2}` declaring the sub libraries:

```
add_library(SubComponent1 SHARED src1.cpp)

# ...

target_link_libraries(MainProject SubComponent1)
```

Note that you can declare [object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) to separate compilation while avoiding multiple library files in the end:

```
add_library(SubComponent1 OBJECT src1.cpp)

# ...

add_library(MainProject $<TARGET_OBJECTS:SubComponent1> ...)
```